# Echarts: How to make categories of relationships or links?

Tags: charts, hyperlink, categories

All the demos of echarts show good performance in categorizing of nodes, but I want to highlight the links of several nodes.

So I am imagining if it is possible to replace the nodes categories of links categories. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The new change of echarts support this requirement

https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/pull/12590